# Inconsistency between background colours on iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I was wondering if anyone may have advice regarding how best to display background colours on different platforms.

I have a image logo, which appears on almost every screen of my application. This logo contains light blue text and a background hex colour of '#1C272A'. I found this hex value from uploading the image to https://html-color-codes.info/colors-from-image/ and selecting the background of the image.

This works perfectly on iOS and there is a seamless transition from the image to the background colour of the application. However, when using the same background colour on Android, there is a clear difference between the background colour of my image and the background colour of the application, even though the same hex value is being used. On Android, the background hex colour is closer to '#0C2331', however I still haven't got this to match perfectly.

I would love to know if there is a way to quickly convert iOS displayed colours to Android displayed colours, as at the moment I've been fiddling around with the hex values for two hours and still haven't got it to match perfectly on Android.

Comment: Might be android eye protection  or night mode in android is turned on.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is some difference. For example:

**Samsung screens use differently shaped pixels than iPhone.**

It's called a PenTile screen and the main difference is that the red, green, and blue subpixels aren't the same as a normal display.

Basically, instead of each pixel getting a red, green, and blue subpixel that is the same size, a PenTile pixel gets red and green or blue and green subpixels. The red and blue are larger than the green to balance the brightness.

Because there are twice as many green subpixels than red and blue on your phone, your color choice is probably mismatch on these devices.

[For more detail about PenTile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PenTile_matrix_family#Devices)